# If $M$ is a $p$-primary $R$-module, then prove that for any $r\in R, \text{Ann}_M(r)=f(M)$ for some $f\in \text{End}_R(M)$.

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a principal Ideal Domain, $0\neq p$ be a  prime element of $R$ and $M$ be a $p$-primary $R$-module.   Prove that for any $r\in R$,$$\text{Ann}_M(r)=f(M)$$ for some $f\in \text{End}_R(M)$.  Where $\text{Ann}_M(r)=\{m\in M:mr=0\}$.

This is what I know in connection to a $p$-primary module $M$ and every prime $p\in R$:

An $R$-module $M$ is called $p$-primary if $M:=\{m\in M:mp^n=0~\text{for some}~n>0\}.$
For every $p\in R$ we have the ascending chain $\text{Ann}_M(p)\subseteq \text{Ann}_M(p^2)\subseteq\cdots\subseteq\text{Ann}_M(p^n)\subseteq\text{Ann}_M(p^{n+1})\subseteq\cdots$ and in particular, $$M:=\bigcup_{n\geq 1}\text{Ann}_M(p^n).$$  Also for ever $p\in R, \text{Ann}_M(p)$ is a sub-module of $M$.  It seems that the problem requires to show that $\text{Ann}_M(p)$ is an image of $M$, that is, there exists a sub-module $N$ of $M$ such that $$M/N\cong \text{Ann}_M(p).$$However, I cannot breakthrough.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to mean every prime $p\in R$.